# MATLAB: Extract point array from .tif image

Tags: image, matlab

I am relatively new to Matlab image processing stuff. I will be precise:

I have a .tif image which I would like to load into Matlab and subsequently extract an array of points (x,y) by simple mouse clicking. For Example:

I click three times => 3 xy coordinates => 2 dim array in workspace with three rows.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) for loading tif image from disk.
You will find [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) useful for displaying the image you read from disk.
Finally, you can use [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) to interactively mark locations on the displayed image.